# How to stop the continous fines using php

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to stop the continous fines in my codes after I click it and save it in database my problem is because if i click the button it's only save in the return.php but the counting is continuous every day like in the picture, I already try it but it didn't work

> view_borrow.php

```
<div class="container">
<form method="POST" action="return_save.php">
    <div class="margin-top">
        <div class="row">   
            <div class="span12">        
                    <div class="alert alert-info"><strong>Borrowed Books</strong></div>
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table" id="example">

                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Book title</th>                                 
                                    <th>Borrower</th>                                 
                                    <th>Type</th>                                 
                                    <th>Date Borrow</th>                                 
                                    <th>Due Date</th>                            
                                    <th>Date Returned</th>
                                    <th>Fines</th>
                                    <th>Borrow Status</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                              <?php  $user_query=mysqli_query($dbcon,"select * from borrow
                            LEFT JOIN member ON borrow.member_id = member.member_id
                            LEFT JOIN borrowdetails ON borrow.borrow_id = borrowdetails.borrow_id
                            LEFT JOIN book on borrowdetails.book_id =  book.book_id 
                            ORDER BY borrow.borrow_id DESC
                              ")or die(mysqli_error());
                                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($user_query)){


$currentdate = date('Y/m/d');

$start = new DateTime($returndate=$row['due_date']); 

$end = new DateTime($currentdate);



$fines =0;

if(strtotime($currentdate) > strtotime($returndate)){
$days= $start->diff($end, true)->days;


$fines = $days > 0 ? intval(floor($days)) * 15 : 0;

$fi = $row['borrow_details_id'];
mysqli_query($dbcon,"update borrowdetails set fines='$fines' where borrow_details_id = '$fi'");

}

                                $id=$row['borrow_id'];
                                $book_id=$row['book_id'];
                                $borrow_details_id=$row['borrow_details_id'];

                                    ?>
                                <tr class="del<?php echo $id ?>">


                                <td class="test"><?php echo $row['book_title']; ?></td>
                                <td class="test"><?php echo $row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname']; ?></td>
                                <td class="test"><?php echo $row['type']; ?></td>
                                <td class="test"><?php echo $row['date_borrow']; ?></td> 
                                <td class="test"><?php echo $row['due_date']; ?> </td>
                                <td class="test"><?php echo $row['date_return']; ?> </td>
                                 <td class="test"><?php echo "₱ ".$fines; ?></td>
                                <td class="test"><?php echo $row['borrow_status'];?></td>
                                <td > <a rel="tooltip"  title="Return" id="<?php echo $borrow_details_id; ?>"
                                 href="#delete_book<?php echo $borrow_details_id; ?>" data-toggle="modal"   
                                  class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-check icon-large"></i>Return</a>
                                <?php include('modal_return.php'); ?>
                                <td></td> 

                                </tr>
                                <?php  }  ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>


        </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

this is the modal where I click the return button

> modal_return.php

```
    <div id="delete_book<?php echo $borrow_details_id; ?>" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="alert alert-success">Do you want to Return this Book?</div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a class="btn btn-success" href="return_save.php<?php echo '?id='.$id; ?>&<?php echo 'book_id='.$book_id; ?>">Yes</a>
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-remove icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[This is the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJNky.png)

Comment: What is a continuous fine here?

Comment: "like in the picture" what picture?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you want from us? Imagine you're talking to a 5 year old and have to explain this. We have no idea what you're trying to do or what you're talking about.

Comment: @xander already edited guys thank you for response

Comment: @ctwheels already edited the post sorry for inconvenience

Comment: @riocollins it's because you're using the current date. Use instead the `due date` and `date returned` OR `current date` if `date returned` is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing a date diff between `$start` and `$end` (`$currentdate`) but never using `$returndate`. PHP 7 has a null coalesce operator `??` that would be handy for your scenario (otherwise just use a normal `if/else` or its ternary equivalent `?:`).

Your fees will always be from `borrowdate` to `currentdate` with your existing code. The code below should fix your issue.

```
$borrowdate = new Datetime($row['due_date']);
$currentdate = new Datetime();
$returndate = new Datetime($row['date_return']);

// PHP >= 7
$days = $borrowdate->diff($returndate ?? $currentdate, true)->days;

// PHP < 7
$days = $borrowdate->diff($returndate ?: $currentdate, true)->days;
```

Comment: there's an error https://imgur.com/a/HNjDN  thank you for your effort my friend, my php is 5.6 so I try your bottom code

Comment: My apologies @riocollins, formatting the `Datetime` object returns a string. I removed the `format('Y/m/d')`. Now it should work

Comment: You don't need to use `strtotime` function. It's just saying that a string wasn't provided to the function as it's expecting (you're sending the `Datetime` object, not the formatted string value for the datetime object). I've confirmed that the section of code I've posted as an answer works properly (copy and paste it into phptester.net and echo the result).

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/v9H5J , I already change the date into august 27 but all fines continously again, sorry

Comment: @riocollins Try the code now. I changed the variables coming from the SQL query, should work now.

Comment: @ctwheelsit's not working, the $borrowdate = new Datetime($row['date_borrow']);
  $currentdate = new Datetime();
   $returndate = new Datetime($row['due_date']); is working but all fines  all changes, I want to stop the counting if I click the return button. that's what i mean

Comment: Well if it's returned you edit the `date_return` value in your database. The next time the page is loaded it'll display the book as being returned and fee stops calculating (the fee still shows, but it won't keep counting because the book has been returned)

Comment: It's working!! but after I only click the return, Example If I borrowed the book  on August 15 and due date at August 18, and the current date now is August 20, the fines display zero but if I click return in August 20, the fines will display in August 21 (only counted the fines at  August 20)